# Newtonsoft JSON DefaultSettings per Assembly

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net

In order to automatically trim all input strings and remove new lines, I developed an implementation of `JsonConverter<string>` and registered it in `Startup` with

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
    {
        new StringTrimmer()
    }
};
```

This works, but the string trimmer is negatively impacting third-party assemblies.  Is there a way I can scope the default settings to my application's assembly, or register an instance with `JsonConvert.Create(mySettings)`?  Or is there another method which I could automatically trim all input without JsonConvert?

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about changing how ASP.NET Core serializes JSON, then you can configure the `JsonSerializerSettings` for the MVC framework explicitly using [`AddJsonOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcjsonmvcbuilderextensions.addjsonoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringTrimmer());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically apply your converter only within certain assemblies by using a custom `ContractResolver` like this:

```
public class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private Assembly[] TargetAssemblies { get; set; }

    public CustomResolver(params Assembly[] targetAssemblies)
    {
        TargetAssemblies = targetAssemblies;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization ms)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, ms);

        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string) &&
            TargetAssemblies.Contains(prop.DeclaringType.Assembly))
        {
            prop.Converter = new StringTrimmer();
        }

        return prop;
    }
}
```

Then use it within your default settings like this, where `Foo` is replaced with one of the known classes in your application's assembly:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(typeof(Foo).Assembly)
};
```

You can add more than one assembly if you need to, e.g.:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(typeof(Foo).Assembly, typeof(Bar).Assembly)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `StringTrimmer` aware of the types (and their assemblies) it's dealing with. `WriteJson()` and `ReadJson()` have [access](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to the type of object. Apply the trimming only to the types you care about.